# Get disk usage in a certain time frame

Tags: disk-usage

I'd like to know, which files/directories have been created in a certain time frame (e.g. the last 7 days) that have contributed significantly to an increase in disk usage.

Output similar to

```
du /root -ah --max-depth 2 --time
```

would be sufficient, e.g.

```
$ show-disk-usage /root --since 2020-12-01 --till now --max-depth 2
1,1M    2020-12-01 03:41    /root/dir1/sub1
2,0M    2020-12-12 05:46    /root/dir1/sub2
3,2M    2020-12-09 17:01    /root/dir1/file
6,3M    2020-12-12 05:46    /root/dir1
1,1M    2020-12-01 03:41    /root/dir2/sub1
2,0M    2020-12-10 21:30    /root/dir2/sub2
3,2M    2020-12-09 17:01    /root/dir2/file
6,3M    2020-12-10 21:30    /root/dir2
12,6M   2020-12-12 05:46    /root
```

with the 3 columns

```
disk-usage-sum-of-modified-files   last-modification-time   file-or-directory-path
```

Unlike `du` only the files in the given time frame should be shown and added to the sum of their directory.
E.g. a file `/root/dir1/file2` modified on `2020-08-01 12:01` of size `9,8M` should not change the output of the example given above.

**Bonus:** An option `--threshold` like `du --threshold 1M` would be great to get only files that contributed **significantly** to an increase in disk usage. However, this option should not change the sum of the directory, since smaller files may accumulate to consume a large amount of disk space.

**Bonus 2:** Instead of modification time it may be better to use creation time of files, since a small change of a large file may not be what you are looking for. Options `--created-since`, `--created-till`, `--modified-since` and `--modified-till` would be an improvement.

---

Note: The solution does not have to be a command line application.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `find` and `du` to do this

```
find /home/vtrefny -type f -mmin -$((7 * 24 * 60)) -printf "%p\0" | du -h -t 1M --time --files0-from=-
```

`find` arguments

- `-mmin` -- files last modified X minutes ago (`cmin` and `amin` can be used for creation/access time)
- `-$((7 * 24 * 60))` -- 7 days in minutes
- `-printf "%p\0"` -- print file path with trailing NUL byte (`du` needs it)

`du` arguments

- `--time` -- print last modification time (`--time=<ctime/atime>` can be used for creation/access time) .
- `--files0-from=-` -- read file list from stdin (provided by `find` here)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to define depth? If I append `--max-depth` it does not change the output.

Comment: It also does not show the sum of directories.

Comment: You can get the sum with `-c` with `du` but that's just total sum, I'm afraid this wont work for the individual directories.